# Iterate through two parallel collections and output a third one

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, iteration, directory

I have two folders containing two the same list of files with almost identical numbers.

```
**Folder_XX:**
- xx_file1.xml
- xx_file2.xml
... 
- xx_fileN.xml

**Folder_YY:**
- yy_file1_bkabka.xml
- yy_file2_blabla.xml
... 
- yy_fileN_zedzed.xml
```

For each file in the first folder I need to do a transformation using also data from the equivalent file in the second folder.

In other wordds, I have a XSLT stylesheet that I can successfully run on, say, **Folder_XX/xx_file1.xml** and it uses some content from its equivalent file in the other folder by means of `document('Folder_YY/yy_file1_bkabka.xlf')`. I would need to do the same for all files.

I can think of one approach:

- Rename all files in **Folder_YY** so that their name matches their equivalent file in **Folder_XX**
- Give the name of the input file to the stylesheet to get content from `document('Folder_YY/$inputFileName')`
- Iterate through the input files in **Folder_XX** running the stylesheet on each of them from the command line.

However, perhaps in XSLT it's possible to do it more efficiently from inside the stylesheet? e.g. providing the paths to the two folders as parameters when running the stylesheet from the command line?

Taking the files recursively by their position in the list would be ideal, but if not possible, renaming files in **Folder_YY**, but that's not an issue.

The result files can be named as the input files, perhaps with a suffix like `_out.xml`, e.g. input: Folder_XX/xx_file1.xml -> output: Folder_XX_Out/xx_file1_out.xml.

I'll be grateful for any tips or recommendations.

**UPDATE**

This is the stylesheet I would run as `java -jar saxon9he.jar Folder_XX/xx_file1.xml my.xsl`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- this fetches the source node from the yy file -->
    <xsl:key name="ref" match="trans-unit" use="@id"/> 
    <xsl:template match="source">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', ../@id, document('Folder_YY/yy_file1_bkabka.xml'))/source" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- everything else comes from the the xx file -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE WITH FINAL STYLESHEET**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('Folder_XX?select=xx_file*.xml')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="output-name" select="replace(
            tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()], 
            '(.+)\.xml', 
            '$1_out.xml'
        )"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="output-folder/{$output-name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="trans-unit" use="@id"/> 
    <xsl:template match="source">
        <xsl:variable name="input-uri" select="document-uri(/)" />
        <xsl:variable name="secondary-input" select="replace(
            replace($input-uri, 'Folder_XX', 'Folder_YY'), 
            'xx_(file[0-9]+)\.xml', 
            'yy_$1.xml'
        )"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', ../@id, doc($secondary-input))/source" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use or can you use? For instance with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 using e.g. `collection('Folder_XY?select=xx_file*.xml')` you can certainly pull in the selection of files and also identify the corresponding files from the other folder. I am currently not sure whether you want to produce a single transformation result from all files or whether you want to produce several ones, but the latter would be possible using `xsl:result-document` in XSLT 2.0 as well.

Comment: It would also help if you show the existing code you have, in particular the match to the root node `/` or the root element `/*`.

Comment: I am using SaxonHE 9.7.0.15 with XSLT 2.0. The output of the transformation should see one output file for each input file, so another folder with as many files as files as contained in the input folder (xx).

Comment: With Saxon 9 you can process a collection of files as already indicated in my earlier comment. The disadavantage is that it pulls all those files into memory unless you use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/functions/saxon/discard-document.html which is only available in the commercial editions PE/EE. You have not explained how you want to name the result files, so you might want to add that info to your question.

Comment: Thank you, Matin. I have a collection of 70 files (times two folders) with most of them under 100 kb, so I think it should be fine with 8GB of RAM. The result files can be named as the input files, perhaps with a suffix like `_out.xml`. I will update the question with this info and will try out your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process a single file using Saxon from the command line without having to hardcode the file name of the secondary file you could use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="input-uri" select="document-uri(/)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="secondary-uri" select="replace(replace($input-uri, 'Folder_XX', 'Folder_YY'), 'xx_(file[0-9+)\.xml', 'yy_($1)_bkabka.xml')"/>

    <!-- this fetches the source node from the yy file -->
    <xsl:key name="ref" match="trans-unit" use="@id"/> 
    <xsl:template match="source">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', ../@id, doc($secondary-input))/source" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- everything else comes from the the xx file -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to process a collection of files I would start with a named template e.g. `-it:main` and there use

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('Folder_XX?select=xx_file*.xml')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document href="output-folder/result{position()}.xml">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

(the computed output file name is just an example, you could of course use parts of the input file name) and then you would need to compute the file name as before, only in

```
    <xsl:template match="source">
        <xsl:variable name="input-uri" select="document-uri(/)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="secondary-uri" select="replace(replace($input-uri, 'Folder_XX', 'Folder_YY'), 'xx_(file[0-9+)\.xml', 'yy_($1)_bkabka.xml')"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', ../@id, doc($secondary-input))/source" />
    </xsl:template>
```

so you should end up with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('Folder_XX?select=xx_file*.xml')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document href="output-folder/result{position()}.xml">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

    <!-- this fetches the source node from the yy file -->
    <xsl:key name="ref" match="trans-unit" use="@id"/> 

    <xsl:template match="source">
        <xsl:variable name="input-uri" select="document-uri(/)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="secondary-uri" select="replace(replace($input-uri, 'Folder_XX', 'Folder_YY'), 'xx_(file[0-9+)\.xml', 'yy_($1)_bkabka.xml')"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', ../@id, doc($secondary-input))/source" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- everything else comes from the the xx file -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I think you understood the thing, so your code should work. I've added your suggestions to my stylesheet, I've added more memory to _JAVA_OPTIONS by creating system environment variables and I have run the transformation with `java -jar saxonb9-1-0-8j/saxon9.jar -it:main -xsl:my.xsl
`. Alas, I get this error: `XTDE1270: Cannot call the key() function when there is no context item` (on the line where it is trying to use the ref key), which I think might be familiar to you (check https://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/mailman/message/28208487/). Any tips?

Comment: I understand the `collection` function used in the `main` template is iterating through the files in the folder and sending each one to the `input-uri` variable, so no other link between fetching the collection and using each input file is needed.

Comment: I can't explain the error message in a template with a `match` attribute so I am not sure what is wrong. As exchanging code in comments is difficult, you might want to edit your question and show the complete stylesheet you now have.

Comment: @msoutopico, I have also edited the answer and added the complete stylesheet I imagine for the complete solution reading in all files with `collection` and creating a result document for each processed input document in the collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Martin. I see we had the same code but you put the two variables inside the `source` template, I suppose so that they are in scope for each file. I will post my final stylesheet. Thank you!

Comment: I am also trying to compute the name of the result file: I create a variable named `output-uri` inside the `source` variable and then I change the output line to `<xsl:result-document href="output-folder/{$output-uri}">`, but it says the declaration of the variable is not in scope and I don't know how to circumvenct that.

Comment: You will need to put the computation of the result href into the template matching `/` e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:variable name="output-name" select="replace(tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()],  'xx_(file[0-9+)\.xml', 'xx_($1)_out.xml')"/> <xsl:result-document href="output-folder/{$output-name}">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147092/discussion-between-msoutopico-and-martin-honnen).

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Of course it works if you take the basename from the `document-uri` (which is global) rather than from the `$input-uri` (which is inside the template matching `source`). All my gratitude for your great help.